# compress data into existing zipfile subdir from stdin

Tags: linux, zip, compression, gzip, ksh

I know it is possible to pipe stdin into a zipfile.
However, is it also possible to do this, while providing the target subdirectory of an existing zipfile?

e.g., something like

```
echo thisshouldbezipped > gzip -u mycurzipfile.zip mysubdirinzip
```

Comment: why on earth a minus without some comment? This is a geniune question and i cannot get any info from the man pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You speak of a *zipfile* and also of `gzip`, but `gzip` creates neither a `.zip` file nor an archive file with a subdirectory, so let's concentrate on `zip`.

Unfortunately, `zip` has no option to specify a *target subdirectory* for the file from standard input, so we would have to resort to a temporary file, e. g.:

```
( cd /tmp
  mkdir mysubdirinzip
  echo thisshouldbezipped >mysubdirinzip/-
  zip mycurzipfile.zip mysubdirinzip/-
  rm -r mysubdirinzip
)
mv /tmp/mycurzipfile.zip .
```

Comment: hi, thank you for confirming this. It was just a performance consideration. and it would have been nice to be able to skip writing to disk. The records come from a pipe.